# Creating Model classes in a MVC based applications

Tags: spring-mvc, model

I am learning Spring MVC. And in most of the examples and tutorials i have seen that a simple Model class is created by defining private variables and providing setters and getters methods for them

for example like the one below

```
public static class Person  {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName";

     public String firstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void firstName(String bar1) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String lastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void lastName(String bar2) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

But i can define the above class by just defining public variables as i am not doing any processing in the getters and setters method, like below

```
public static class Person  {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName";
}
```

and access it like

```
Person objPerson = new Person();
objPerson.firstName = 'Mickey';
objPerson.lastName = 'Mouse';
```

I understand the approach is not very dynamic in the sense if at later point i decide to put some processing logic in getter and setter methods, then i may have to change all my client objects to change to use the getters and setters. but is that all or there is other implications if i take this route?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use getters and setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. Stick to `private` fields and `public` getters/setters. Any Java IDE can generate them based on fields. Most frameworks depends on getters/setters (JPA is a notable exception in field mode) as per the JavaBeans standard.

Save yourself from a lot of headaches and just use the standard approach. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The main argument towards creating getter and setters is for improved encapsulation from an object oriented sense. When you have an object, you are interacting with the object via its public interface. By accessing the instance variables directly, you are no longer interacting with the object, but rather with its internal implementation.

The idea is to create a black box, where the internals are hidden. A getter / setter method may go out to a database, or a filesystem, or a local instance variable to retrieve the model data. If those underlying data sources change in some later update, you will only have to change the getter / setter methods, whereas if you access the variables directly, you will have to refactor your entire code base.